# Problem with macro definition spaces of index and superscript

Tags: macros, spacing, xspace

I have defined a command `FZ` for defining mathematical symbols:

```
\newcommand{\FZ}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\ensuremath{#1}}\xspace}
```

I want to define a Symbol `CV` first and then create some variants with different indices like `CV_D`, `CV_{D,\,\mathrm{Gr}}`...

To make that consistently, I tried to define it "stepwise", but then I get problems with the spacing. See minimal example:

- how can I get the `D` closer to the `CV` like in the black version which is "directly" typeset?
- how can I get the "Gr" on the same height as the index "D"?

[image: screenshot of ME]

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{color, xspace}

\newcommand{\FZ}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\ensuremath{#1}}\xspace}

\newcommand{\CV}{\FZ{CV}}
\newcommand{\CvD}{\FZ{\CV{}^{*}_{D}}}   
\newcommand{\CvDGr}{\FZ{\CvD_{,\,\mathrm{Gr}}}}

\begin{document}

\CV

\CvD

wish: $CV_D$

\CvDGr

wish: $CV^{*}_{D,\,\mathrm{Gr}}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In math mode `{ }` generate a new math object (it's actually called differently AFAIK, but I can't recall the correct name) which influences the placement of sub- and superscripts.
`{{...}_{D}}_{\,Gr}` is simply different than `{...}_{D\,Gr}`.

Also placing it in a color macro has also some influence. Note that you use `\FZ` multiple times int `\CvDGr`. I would simply flatten out the macro definitions. If you really want "consistency" then IMHO you need some macros which do not hold the `\FZ` and also accept more material in form of an argument:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{color, xspace}

\newcommand{\FZ}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\ensuremath{#1}}\xspace}

\newcommand{\cv}{CV}
\newcommand{\CV}{\FZ{\cv}}
\newcommand{\cvd}[1]{\cv^{*}_{D#1}}
\newcommand{\CvD}{\FZ{\cvd{}}}
\newcommand{\CvDGr}{\FZ{\cvd{,\,\mathrm{Gr}}}}

\begin{document}

\CV

\CvD

wish: $CV_D$

\CvDGr

wish: $CV^{*}_{D,\,\mathrm{Gr}}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: thank you! I'll try that approach. The **color** is only used to easily distinguish already consistently defined symbols from those typed "by hand" and will be removed for the final version, when all non-blue math symbols have been checked and changed into blue ones.

Answer (score 5):

My position is to *never* use `\ensuremath` for commands that produce math symbols, which also frees from the `\xspace` problem.

```
\newcommand{\FZ}{\textcolor{blue}}
\newcommand{\CV}{\FZ{CV}}
\newcommand{\CvD}{\FZ{CV^{*}_{D}}}
\newcommand{\CvDGr}{\FZ{CV^{*}_{D,\,\mathrm{Gr}}}}
```

The "D" in your `\CvD` is far because of the empty subformula you inserted with `{}`; the "Gr" was not in the same subscript, so it was treated as a subscript of an empty formula, hence it was a bit raised because the "D" was pushed down by the presence of the superscript.

Now $\CV$, $\CvD$ and $\CvDGr$ work without problems. If you *really* want `\ensuremath`, put it outside the color command:

```
\newcommand{\FZ}[1]{\ensuremath{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}\xspace}
```

Indeed `\textcolor{blue}{x}` works also in math mode, producing an ordinary symbol; since your objects are ordinary symbols, there's no problem.

Comment: thanks! So you mean, it is better to explicitely write `$...$` around all math commands? What happens then, if I use one already defined command "in" another one? E. g. I define `\D` as $D$ and later use it in `\CVD` which shall look like `$CV_{\D}$`? (The hint about the color command is extremely helpful as well!)

Comment: Keep math as math and non math as non math. Where's the gain from `$D$` to `\D`?

Comment: $D$ is a variable describing a product property, I'm using very often. Should I decide to call it $d$ later, I'd like to be able to change that easily. And  same for e. g. the coefficient of variation of the property `\D` which originally was called `CV_{D}`, but might have to change his name. I'm also using a lot of indices which shall be easily toggled between english and german, for example. Defining those commands proved very helpful for me, as I (a) am not very good in regular expressions, so (b) the risk would be too high to destroy something with simple find and replace...

Comment: p.s. it does not end with `$CV_D$`, but there are the D's and CV_D's of different product states during the manufacturing process. I've made up a quite complicated system, but I prefer defining it once and using it consistently to reduce the risk of errors.

Comment: So define it by `\newcommand{\D}{D}`. I really don't see any advantage in being able to write `\D` in text instead of `$\D$`, when this adds complications to the definitions; `$\D$` is straigthforward, well visible in the input file, and has no "spaces problems".

Comment: ... but $\D$ increases the keyboard input about 100% (and I have a lot of \D's (and similar symbols) in my text and in my figures...). ;-) Thanks for your patience and for your suggestion - I'll consider that, however in this advanced state it would not be easy (at least for me) to change all the source code from \D to $\D$ without damaging something.

Comment: Being wary of `\ensuremath` in the general case from answers like yours, are there any drawbacks for the particular instance `\ensuremath{\left(...\right)}` ?  Would `\mbox{$\left(...\right)$}` be preferable?  Or would they both screw up things like sub/superscript spacings and/or other things? (It doesn't seem to at first glance)